# Cannot resize partition

Tags: laptop

Good morning,

I have only Elementary installed on my computer and I need to resize (increase) the boot partition.
That means to decrease the main partition (900GB) and then increase the other one.

I have created a bootable USB, launched it, selected the "try" option and opened the Gparted. I have "deactivated the main partition (no lock icon next to it) and then clicked on the resize.

This is when the problem arrives. I cannot change the size at all. The Gparted tells me that the minimum size is 900 GB and the maximum size is also 900 GB. This also happens when I try to do the custom install, I cannot even get past the screen where I can resize partitions. I can do only standard fresh install without changing the size of partitions.

I thought that it might be because of the main partition to be encrypted. So I did the reinstallation so the main partition is not encrypted, but nothing has changed.

I am also including photos of what these screens look like. Do not get fooled by the lock icon, I took the picture after I reactivated it. Normally it is not there.

Any help would be appreciated.

I do not mind to to a new fresh installation again, but as mentioned above, even that (custom installation) did not help.

Thank you
Peter

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you are using an LVM, you will need to first resize that, *then* resize `/dev/sda2` 